# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' python

Tags: python, types

I'm trying to run this code in python:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=num_splits)
n = 0
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(mask_list):
    with open(join(outdir,'train_split_' + str(n) + '.csv'), 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for i in train_index:
            writer.writerow([basename(mask_list[i])])
    with open(join(outdir,'test_split_' + str(n) + '.csv'), 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for i in test_index:
            writer.writerow([basename(mask_list[i])])
    n += 1
```

but it gives me:

```
writer.writerow([basename(mask_list[i])])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

What could be?

Comment: use `w` instead of `wb` while opening a file.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a text file format, and as a result the output that the `csv` module produces is a string. You should therefore open the output files in text mode, rather than binary mode:

Change:

```
with open(join(outdir,'train_split_' + str(n) + '.csv'), 'wb') as csvfile:
```

to:

```
with open(join(outdir,'train_split_' + str(n) + '.csv'), 'w') as csvfile:
```

And the same applies to the other output file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3.X then you can use `newline=''`

**Ex:**

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=num_splits)
n = 0
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(mask_list):
    with open(join(outdir,'train_split_' + str(n) + '.csv'), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:    #--> !Update
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for i in train_index:
            writer.writerow([basename(mask_list[i])])
    with open(join(outdir,'test_split_' + str(n) + '.csv'), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:    #--> !Update
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for i in test_index:
            writer.writerow([basename(mask_list[i])])
    n += 1
```